# Regex to find all strings that are not inside balanced parentheses

Tags: regex

I want to find a regex that works in JavaScript and have the logic to find all strings that are not inside balanced parentheses, i.e. all strings that start and finish with the char `"` but are not surrounded by both char `(` and char `)`.

I want that for the text:

```
1. ("ggg" "H"
2. "ggg") "H"
3. ("ggg") "H"
4. "gg()g" "H"
5. "gg)g" "H"
6. "gg(g" "H"
```

1. the matches: "ggg", "H"
2. the matches: "ggg", "H"
3. the matches: "H"
4. the matches: "gg()g", "H"
5. the matches: "gg)g", "H"
6. the matches: "gg(g", "H"

this is what I have for now:
but it doesn't work for strings that have the char `)` inside

```
(?<!\()"[^\)]+?"
```

Comment: [The Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) can make it easier: Match what you don't want, but capture what you need. Eg Something like this: [`\("[^"]+"\)|("[^"]+")`](https://regex101.com/r/ThXEO8/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Trick](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick) can make it easier:  Match what you don't want, *but* [capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) what you need...
`not this|(but that)` and process the matches on JS-side. For your task, eg:

```
\("[^"]+"\)|("[^"]+")
```

[See this demo at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ThXEO8/1) (in the multiline demo `\n` is for not skipping lines)

For extracting, use eg [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) and check if *group 1* is set. If it is set, the match derives from the right side of the alternation (not "inside balanced"). Here a [JS-demo at tio.run using `exec`](https://tio.run/##VY/PDoIwDIfvfYq6C11U1JsJmTcT3wExIWQMzADD8E@iPjt2IAcOTfb9@m3trukjdVlb3rr1Y9/3VnfYaqNfqHBzJhFfRLIUZ/mZjnJjqggga2rXoetax2IMAQljjEBxEsEKggHkRDRHJpIzd070J0h4jp8Q5k17TLOCGFAd4A2I457DcNYQn0VpNRJVatg@1C@deV/KhVL13VrJkr@IWOZUxbtkMcb/EP1r4e3uCm5uExkN6RfG8r9trA5tY4g97n65APr@Bw) or [`replace`](https://tio.run/##VY9BawIxEIXv8yuGXJKw26zepLKWFou9@QPUQlhjtGw2kkQptP3t28laoXsJ@R5v3pv50Fcdm3A6p4frrO9bkzAYaz6xxmor2Oad7Qq2ld/3r6ysmwM0vosJYwqRjBvggllrGbI3xkvgA8g7iTESCTnyjkn8EeyoJzeogw@vujkKAqwX8AWIud@3RrXeZlnOSbvtnhciRQVzbnVjxHBNicJNSjeV9SJPj@fdBAvklExPQcbpE395XvJHvlqvl1wO2YhVhXuPuttTR7qEDqN3Jh1PnUWlFFl@BuP/YBKyCND3vw).